# Semi-automatic classification QGIS plugin not responding

Tags: qgis, classification, scp

Trying to use search in Semi-automatic Classification plugin as part of QGIS and it is not responding. I have searched parameters for Bonn in Germany and dates from 2020-04-01 to 2020-05-07 with cloud cover of 30. Product set to L8 L9 OLI/TIRS

I see Copernicus has changed it portal, is this the issue? What is the new url for sentinels? I was using https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus and also tried https://scihub.copernicus.eu/apihub. My password is recent (not sure if there is a waitime) but I have one.

Any suggestions?